# Differentiation of $e^{2x}$

Tags: derivatives

- I know that the derivative of $$e^{2x} = 2e^{2x}.$$
- However if I change it to its equivalent form $$e^{2^x}$$ the derivative becomes $$2xe^{2x}.$$
- Process for second one:
  $$y=e^{x^2}$$
  $$\ln y=(x^2)\ln(e)$$
  $${dy/dx}=2xe^{2x}$$

I think the problem is that is not the equivalent form, but how come, I thought it was one of the rules.

Comment: $$ (e^2)^x \neq e^{(2^x)} $$

Comment: By the chain rule, since $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$, $$\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x} = \left(\frac{d}{dx}2x\right) e^{2x} = \color{red}{\large 2 e^{2x}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2*x\neq2^x$$
$$e^{2x}\neq e^{2^x}$$
Your problem comes from that. You can't switch them around like that.
I think what you're thinking of is $(a^b)^c=a^{b*c}$.

Comment: Wasn't there a rule where you can just exponents if there was an exponent of an exponent?

Comment: Yes, $(e^x)^2=e^xe^x=e^{2x}$

Comment: An exponent of an exponent is not a multiplication of the exponents. $2^{3^2}=2^9=512\neq 2^{3*2}=2^6=64$

Comment: Oh, yes, that's what I was thinking, thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $e^{2x}$ is **not** equal to $2e^{2x}$. You can write $(e^{2x})' = 2e^{2x}$ or $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}(e^{2x}) = 2e^{2x}$, but not as you initially wrote.

Second, $e^{2x}$ is **not** the same thing as $e^{2^x}$. So from here onwards, it's all unsaveable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is missing parentheses, and the ambiguous notation that results from it.

It is true that $\left( e^x \right)^2 = e^{2x}$, and that the derivative of this (whichever way you choose to write it) is $2e^{2x}$.

It is also true that the derivative of $e^{x^2}$ is $2xe^{x^2}$.

The confusion comes from the fact that  $e^{x^2}$ means $e^{\left(x^2 \right)}$, not $\left( e^x \right)^2$.  They are not equal to each other -- exponentiation is not associative.